# Install pecl on Centos 7 PHP7.4

Tags: php, centos7, pecl

I want to install PECL on centos 7 with php7.4, I use this command on cPanel Terminal:

```
sudo yum install php-pear
```

but I got this error:

```
  file /usr/bin/php from install of php-cli-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ea-php-cli-1.0.0-9.10.1.cpanel.x86_64
```

Comment: I'm not expert in this but seems to be a conflict with pre-installed php-cli. You may want to exclude php-cli from the install.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how I can exclude php-cli from install?